# How can I add dynamically an attribute with VueJS?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I know I can set a value to an attribute dynamically with `v-bind`, however I would like add dynamically **the attribute**, not the value. Something like this (although this is not valid):

```
    <a
      :href="url"
      {{ downloadable ? 'download' : null }}
      class="link"
      @click="onClick">
      {{ text }}
    </a>
```

*Note: I'm not using JSX*

I was thinking about using `$attrs` (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-attrs) but it's read only.

Is there a way to do this on Vue?

**Solution:**

JavaScript:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
       msg: 'Inspect element to test',
       downloadable: true
    }
  },
  computed: {
    dynamicAttribute() {
      if(!this.downloadable) {
         return null
      }

      return { [`download`]: "link or w/e" }
    }
  }
})
```

HTML:

```
  <a v-bind="dynamicAttribute">{{msg}}</a>
```

Comment: Do you mean something like this `:download = "downloadable && 'filename' || null"`?

Comment: No, that's the thing, download is an HTML attribute and it only cares if it's present. I want to avoid rendering `download` in the final HTML base on the prop downloadable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to look like:

`<a ... download="value">text</a>`

with `download` visible only when `downloadable` is true, you can actually do it using `v-bind`:

https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/274691/

You can check if it works by changing `downloadable` to true or false and inspecting the element.

Comment: It seems a little bit hacky but I don't there are much options beside using the DOM. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Other than boolean attribute you cannot dynamically add or set attribute using Vue.js. For example -

```
v-bind:disabled="isActive"
```

If isActive is true, then the attribute **disabled** will be added to the element, otherwise it will be removed. This mechanism doesn't work for other attribute which are not boolean.

You can use Javascript for that purpose -

```
element.setAttribute('attributeName', 'value');
```

Comment: The attribute `download` is not a boolean, it's a string

Comment: Yes, and that's why you can't add this attribute in Vue way

Comment: You need javascript for that. And that's what is explained in my answer. Other than boolean attribute, you can't add or remove it using vue